# How do I select the label before and checked check box?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-selectors, label

I want to apply styles to the label when the checkbox is checked but the label sits before the checkbox.

My code is:

```
<label class="label" for="main-checkbox">LABEL</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="main-checkbox">
```

I've been struggling with the css selectors to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by 'select the label'?

Comment: When the checkbox is checked, I want to apply styles to the label

Comment: You can't only with css if the label is before ...

Comment: So javascript is the only solution then, damn!

Comment: Or you can change your html label after checkbox and with css change the positions

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="main-checkbox">
<label for="main-checkbox"><span></span></label></p>
```

then use CSS

```
p {
    position: relative;
}

p > input[type="checkbox"] {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 3px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    opacity: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

p > input[type="checkbox"] +label {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #555;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

label>span:before {
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 7px;
}

label>span:after {
    display: none;
}

p > input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
    content: 'B';
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #F0F;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 7px;
}

p > input[type="checkbox"] +label:after {
    content: 'A';
    text-indent: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #F0F;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 7px;
}
```

Check out the JSFiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/rzTFP/

I turned the checkbox into a general clickable box.

It works when the label sits after the `<input>` but play around with it.

Comment: Well thats the point, the label sits above the input due to the content being generated and I only have control of the styles. If there isnt a way to do it in css, then thats fair enough

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the "checked" state... It won't work for older browsers, though.

http://jsfiddle.net/CjpmP/

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="check-with-label" />
  <label for="check" class="label-for-check">My Label</label>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.check-with-label:checked + .label-for-check {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I would suggest using javascript so that you use more traditional CSS rules, though... http://jsfiddle.net/MGVHX/1/